# Concurrent HTTP callouts vs single callout

Tags: callout, future, performance

**Background**
I have 3 identical HTTP servers, holding the same data: `api1`, `api2` and `api3`.

I want to query this data as reliable and quick as possible. In Java, I would have done this by spawning 3 threads -- each requesting one of my servers, and used the response that I got first (only waiting for the single fastest reply).

**Question**
Can something similar be done efficiently in Apex (for example with `@future` methods)? There are two things that makes me worried that it won't be efficient:

1. The docs says that "Each future method is queued and executes when system resources become available". This implies that it's slower than regular methods.
2. Since `@future` methods has to return `void`, I have to write the result to the database(?) and setup some trigger logic that detects when the first response has arrived(?). This sounds slower than regular methods as well.

Am I right in my assumptions?

Comment: If you're interested in load balancing, why not just host a load balancer (apiload) that selects the least busiest of the three servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no control over when the future method gets executed after it is queued.
there is no priority mechanism that caller can add to future method.
You are also  correct about your assumption related to future method returning void.

Please note, just for reliability if you are making multiple calls from salesforce to your servers you are adding up to limits on callouts.

I would suggest doing this still in java and pushing the result to salesforce.

Comment: Does recently released Asynchronous callouts(Continuation) address this issue or it's quite unrelated?

Answer (score 1):

Apex is single threaded, so you can't throw out 3 requests and see which is fastest.

@future is exactly what it sounds like: something that happens in the future. That is, it's asynchronous and will occur when the platform gets around to it. Usually in less than a couple of seconds, but definitely outside the execution scope of the method that called the @future method.

Best thing to do in Apex it just hit one server and wait for a response.

Comment: Does recently released Asynchronous callouts(Continuation) address this issue or it's quite unrelated?